# How to Iterate through an array of dictionaries to copy only relevant keys to new dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to iterate through a dictionary array like the following to only copy the 'symbol' and 'product_progress' keys and their corresponding values to new dictionary array.

```
  [{'coin_name': 'Bitcoin', 'coin_id': 'bitcoin', 'symbol': 'btc', 'rank': 1, 'product_progress': 93, 'team': 100, 'token_fundamentals': 100, 'github_activity': 95, 'marketing': 5, 'partnership': 5, 'uniqueness': 5, 'total_score': 96, 'exchange_name': 'Bitfinex', 'exchange_link': 'https://www.bitfinex.com/t/BTCUSD', 'website': 'https://bitcoin.org/en/', 'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/Bitcoin', 'telegram': None, 'whitepaper': 'https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-paper'}, {'coin_name': 'Ethereum', 'coin_id': 'ethereum', 'symbol': 'eth', 'rank': 2, 'product_progress': 87, 'team': 98, 'token_fundamentals': 97, 'github_activity': 100, 'marketing': 5, 'partnership': 5, 'uniqueness': 5, 'total_score': 94, 'exchange_name': 'Gemini', 'exchange_link': 'https://gemini.com/', 'website': 'https://www.ethereum.org/', 'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/ethereum', 'telegram': None, 'whitepaper': 'https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/'}] ...
```

The code I have so far is:

```
    # need to iterate through list of dictionaries
    for index in range(len(projectlist3)):
        for key in projectlist3[index]:
                d['symbol'] = projectlist3[index]['symbol']
                d['token_fundamentals'] = projectlist3[index]['token_fundamentals']

print(d)
```

It's just saving the last entry rather than all of the entries {'symbol': 'eth', 'token_fundamentals': 97}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data:

```
l = [{
    'coin_name': 'Bitcoin',
    'coin_id': 'bitcoin',
    'symbol': 'btc',
    'rank': 1,
    'product_progress': 93,
    'team': 100,
    'token_fundamentals': 100,
    'github_activity': 95,
    'marketing': 5,
    'partnership': 5,
    'uniqueness': 5,
    'total_score': 96,
    'exchange_name': 'Bitfinex',
    'exchange_link': 'https://www.bitfinex.com/t/BTCUSD',
    'website': 'https://bitcoin.org/en/',
    'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/Bitcoin',
    'telegram': None,
    'whitepaper': 'https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-paper'
}, {
    'coin_name': 'Ethereum',
    'coin_id': 'ethereum',
    'symbol': 'eth',
    'rank': 2,
    'product_progress': 87,
    'team': 98,
    'token_fundamentals': 97,
    'github_activity': 100,
    'marketing': 5,
    'partnership': 5,
    'uniqueness': 5,
    'total_score': 94,
    'exchange_name': 'Gemini',
    'exchange_link': 'https://gemini.com/',
    'website': 'https://www.ethereum.org/',
    'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/ethereum',
    'telegram': None,
    'whitepaper': 'https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/'
}]
```

You can use [listcomp](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
new_l = [{field: d[field] for field in ['symbol', 'token_fundamentals']}
         for d in l]
```

which is better equivalent of this:

```
new_l = []
for d in l:
    new_d = {}
    for field in ['symbol', 'token_fundamentals']:
        new_d[field] = d[field]
    new_l.append(new_d)
```

Comment: It works thanks! But I do not understand it at all :/

Comment: Thanks. Added explanation.

Comment: @Miller42 Note, that this option is less efficient than [NoahResch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741184/10824407)'s, because it iterates over all dictionary pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what your writing into `d` you want to save a list of objects so this would work:

```
[{"symbol": i['symbol'], "token_fundamentals": i['token_fundamentals']} for i in d]
```

Result:

```
[{'symbol': 'btc', 'token_fundamentals': 100}, {'symbol': 'eth', 'token_fundamentals': 97}]
```